# Python Pandas: How to set value of a cell based on a formula

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to set the value of a single cell within a large dataframe based on a formula from other cells elsewhere in the df. Here's the key part of the code:

```
df.loc[df['Category'] == 'Total', 'Tot Wgt'] = df.loc[df['Category'] == 'B', 'Wgt']
```

So in the row where 'Category' is 'Total' I want the 'Tot Wgt' column to be set to whatever 'B' and 'Wgt' equal. However my code above just outputs a blank. Any ideas?

EDIT TO ADD

(Simpler version of) Dataframe looks something like this:

```
Index    Category    Wgt    Tot Wgt
0        A           5
1        B           2
2        C           11
3        Total              2
```

All the "Category" column items are unique.

Comment: It is expected, because different boolean mask in both sides.

Comment: Show us a sample of the dataframe

Comment: Please check last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for avoid index alignment:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'Category':['A','B','C','D','E', 'Total'],
                   'Wgt':[5,3,6,9,2,4],})

print (df)
   A Category  Wgt
0  a        A    5
1  b        B    3
2  c        C    6
3  d        D    9
4  e        E    2
5  f    Total    4

df.loc[df['Category'] == 'Total', 'Tot Wgt'] = df.loc[df['Category'] == 'B', 'Wgt'].values
print (df)
   A Category  Wgt  Tot Wgt
0  a        A    5      NaN
1  b        B    3      NaN
2  c        C    6      NaN
3  d        D    9      NaN
4  e        E    2      NaN
5  f    Total    4      3.0
```

**Details**:

If indices are different and want assign rows get NaNs.

```
print (df.loc[df['Category'] == 'B'])
   A Category  Wgt
1  b        B    3 <-index is 1

print (df.loc[df['Category'] == 'Total'])
   A Category  Wgt
5  f    Total    4 <-index is 5
```